# How to programmatically get list of active ipv6 connections on windows XP

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, ipv6

I need to get the list of all the active IPV6 connections on windows XP. On windows Vista onwards, Microsoft windows has introduce API GetTcp6Table but on Windows XP I couldn't find any way to find list of active connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP (SP2+) exposes [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which includes the ip version.